# How do I make the link clickable in the rendered template in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am doing a Django project, named PhoneRadar. I have a template page (**details.html**), which looks like this:
[image]
As you can see, the link is not clickable. How can I make it clickable?

Here are my codes of **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.model_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    # slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article
```

Here are my codes of **details.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">


<html lang="en">

{% block title%}Details{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>This is the Details Page</h1>

<h2>Review:</h2>
<p>{{ review.review_article }}</p>

<h2>News Link:</h2>
<p>{{ review.link }}</p>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you use `p` but need `a` for clickable link. More info [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

```
<h2>News Link:</h2>
<a href={{ review.link }}>{{ review.link }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, paragraph tag doesn't directly support link, instead you should use the `a` tag as shown below

`<a href={{ review.link }}>{{ review.link }}</a>`